# Como faço para ver quais commits alteram um certo arquivo?

Tags: git, commit

Eu implementei uma nova funcionalidade para o meu programa em um arquivo Func1.cpp, no ramo `Func1`. Em seguida, criei mais uma funcionalidade — no arquivo Func2.cpp —, mas me esqueci de criar em um *branch* separado `Func2`. Agora, gostaria de separar um ramo para cada funcionalidade.

Para isso, preciso saber quais *commits* alteram o arquivo Func1.cpp e quais alteram Func2.cpp. Assim, posso fazer um `rebase --interactive` para, em seguida, separar os ramos.
Tentei `git show <SHA1>`, mas ele me mostra informações de `diff` que eu não preciso.

**Pergunta:**
Como posso descobrir quais *commits* alteram quais arquivos?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```git
git log <arquivo>
```

Para fazer com que o git entenda e *siga* o arquivo mesmo quando renomeado:

```git
git log --follow <arquivo>
```

Comment: A flag `--follow` deve ser usada antes de `<arquivo>`?

Comment: @VictorHugo Sim! Boa observação.

Comment: caso você esteja em um branch e queira verificar as mudanças em outro é possível utilizar `git log --follow outro_branch -- <arquivo>`.

Comment: @BrunoCoimbra O que significa esse `--`? Já o utilizei antes para resetar modificações em um arquivo: `git checkout -- <arquivo>`.

Comment: @VictorHugo `--` no paramêtro `--follow` não tem nenhum sentido especial, é apenas uma convenção. Normalmente opções simples (uma letra) são acompanhadas de um traço, e opções completas (palavras inteiras) de dois traços (caso do `--follow`). Já o uso isolado de `--`no *git checkout* é uma maneira de dizer para git que você está se referindo a um arquivo (e não a um eventual branch).

Comment: o `--` é utilizado para indicar que as opções da linha de comando acabaram. como o `git` aceita opções nos formatos `-h`, `--help`, `nome_do_branch` e `nome_do_arquivo` é necessário, de alguma forma, diferenciar os 2 últimos formatos.

Answer (score 2):

Recomendo usar um alias no .gitconfig para consultar esse tipo de informação. Coloque no seu `~/.gitconfig`, na seção de aliases:

```
[alias]
    ll = log --pretty=format:"%C(yellow)%h%Cred%d\\ %Creset%s%Cblue\\ [%cn]" --decorate --numstat
```

Pronto, agora `git ll` vai dar um relatório de cada commit com a lista de arquivos alterados por ele, parecido com:

```
afe7f7c first commit [Elias]
2       0       src/main.py
11      0       src/dataset.py

f732435 adicionado notebook [Elias]
100     0       testes.ipynb
```

Answer (score 1):

Ao invés de `git show` tente `git log <nome do arquivo>`.