# Como saber qual foi o último commit a mexer em um mesmo arquivo que o meu commit?

Tags: git

Eu cheguei a ler a questão [Como faço para ver quais commits alteram um certo arquivo?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/148/como-fa%C3%A7o-para-ver-quais-commits-alteram-um-certo-arquivo) Ela é quase o que eu preciso, no caso o que eu quero saber se é possível eu pegar o último commit que alterou qualquer arquivo que eu tenha alterado.

Isso é possível? Ou eu tenho que dar um `git log <arquivo>` em todos os arquivos que eu alterei e pegar o commit mais recente?

Comment: acho git blame <arquivo> pode te ajudar.

Comment: Mas se eu quiser em todos os arquivos modificados? Justamente não ter que fazer um por um.

Comment: Entendi, bem parecido com os detalhes do github né?

Comment: É, mais ou menos...

Comment: Por alterado você quer dizer um arquivo que já adicionou ao stage porém ainda não fez o commit?

Comment: Ou todos os arquivos modificados no último commit?

Comment: Já commitados, mas qual o último commit antes desse que mexeu em algum dos arquivos commitados.

Comment: A pergunta não ficou clara e sem exemplos, Mas pela resposta do pessoal o tópico ficou bastante interessante. Se possível melhore a qualidade da pergunta

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A partir do diretório raiz do repositório:

```
git diff --name-only <rev>^! | xargs git log <rev>^ -1 --
```

Onde `<rev>` é o SHA-1 (ou pedaço de SHA-1) do seu commit que contêm os arquivos que você modificou.

Este comando faz:

- `git diff --name-only <rev>^!`: Cria uma listagem dos arquivos modificados no commit.
- `| xargs`: repassa a listagem em uma única string separada por espaços para o comando a seguir.
- `git log <rev>^ -1 --`: Gera o log de antes do seu commit (por isso `^`), com uma única entrada (por isso `-1`) e tomando como base os arquivos da listagem repassados ao final do comando.

O comando `git log` quando recebe múltiplos arquivos como argumento, vai fazer um log dos commits onde quaisquer deles apareçam somente. Assim o primeiro que aparecer, é o que você quer.

Nota que se seus arquivos possuem espaço no nome ou caminho relativo, o comando provavelmente precisa ser alterado.

Answer (score 8):

Amigo você pode usar

```
git log <arquivo>
```

e para fazer com que o git entenda e siga o arquivo.

```
git log --follow <arquivo>
```

Pode seguir pela branch.

```
git log --follow outro_branch -- <arquivo>
```

Pode ver quem alterou determinado arquivo

```
git blame filename
```

Mas por exemplo. Se dois desenvolvedores tiverem feito 5 commits para o projeto, com

> git shortlog

você vai obter essa saída:

```
/#: git shortlog

Mary (2):
      Fix a bug in the feature
      Fix a serious security hole in our framework

John (3):
      Add the initial code base
      Add a new feature
      Merge branch 'feature'
```

Comment: Então bastaria seguir todos os arquivos do commit, certo? Essa solução me interessa. Há alguma forma de declarar vários arquivos para seguir de uma vez?

Comment: Não seria melhor seguir a branch então ?

Comment: É que acredito que a dúvida do OP seja sobre como verificar que commits alteraram apenas os arquivos que o desenvolvedor alterou, e não todos do branch. Esta solução me agrada pois posso fazer um script para seguir automaticamente qualquer arquivo que eu altere, por exemplo. Resolve. Mas se houver alguma alternativa que dispense isso, ficaria mais feliz ainda. BTW +1.

Comment: Não estou  casa agora se não te ajudaria, estou pelo Cel. Se eu achar posto aqui

Comment: Estou vendo aqui uma solução, mas só para ficar claro, quando você segue a branch claro que você vai ver apenas os arquivos alterados pelos desenvolvedores, pois os logs são feitos encima de alterações, se elas não ocorrem obviamente elas não irão aparecer.

Comment: Com esse aqui você vê quem alterou o arquivo. git blame filename   e esse aqui as alterações de um determinado arquivo gitk filename.

Comment: Vou editar minha resposta com algo que pode te ajudar mais. Se for desnecessário eu removo.

Comment: Para maiores informações : https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/git-log/filtering-the-commit-history

Answer (score 2):

Sempe tem o:

```
git whatchanged <path>.
```

O comando lista todos os commits que mexeram no mesmo path que foi passado por parâmetro.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar simplesmente usar `git log` na pasta principal do branch. Você também pode filtrar por usuarios nesse caso `git log --author=Foo`

Answer (score 0):

Não sei se entendi bem, mas vou tentar responder o trecho abaixo que retirei da sua pergunta. Se não for isso que esteja procurando, tente dar exemplos para tentarmos ajudar.

> "...no caso o que eu quero saber se é possível eu pegar o último commit que alterou qualquer arquivo que eu tenha alterado."?

Se você quizer o **último commit** pode usar:

```
git log -1
```

E conforme resposta anterior do Talles (referenciada na pergunta), se você quer ver o **último commit de um arquivo específico**:

```
git log --follow <arquivo>
```